# Simultaneous forecasting and classification

Tags: classification, long-short-term-memory, time-series, forecasting

I'm working on a project where I need to perform both forecasting (regression) and classification using time series data. The dataset is labelled.

I've been exploring LSTM networks due to their effectiveness in handling sequential data.

Is it possible to use a single LSTM model for both forecasting and classification tasks?

Comment: What do you mean by a single model? Multi-Task learning is a good option, it would be a model with multiple outputs.

Comment: Do you mean something like both deciding if an image is of a dog, cat, or alligator (classification) AND how tall the animal is (regression)?

Comment: @Dave yes this is a similar case.